# Button inside echo

Tags: php, codeigniter, button

Here is my php codeigniter view to show Time(If it is null,it will shows ERROR).

```
<input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" id="checkInTime" name="checkInTime" value="<?php if ($result->checkInTime == '0'||'NULL'){ echo 'ERROR';} else{ echo date('H:i:s',strtotime($result->checkInTime));}?>" required parsley-maxlength="6" placeholder="checkInTime" disabled/>
```

How can i change the ERROR into a button or link(Which is inside the echo).

Comment: Do you want to show the button/link instead of time picker (If checkInTime is NULL) ?

Comment: Just you can put button or <a> tag inside echo '<button>Submit</button>' like this, As PHP supprts HTML inside the double or single quote

Comment: @GajananKolpuke Do _NOT_ put a `<button>` or `<a>` element inside an `<input>` fields `value` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use if condition outside the input:

```
<?php
    if ($result->checkInTime == 0 || $result->checkInTime == NULL) {
     // here echo your button or link 
    } else { ?>
     <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" id="checkInTime" name="checkInTime" value="<?php echo date('H:i:s',strtotime($result->checkInTime));}?>" required parsley-maxlength="6" placeholder="checkInTime" disabled/>
  <?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sawe way that you echo **ERROR**, echo the HTML you want to render, within quotes (balance the quotes and escape them appropriately).

You could use something like this -

```
<input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" id="checkInTime" name="checkInTime" value="<?php if ($result->checkInTime == '0'||'NULL'){ echo "<button class=\"button-class\" value=\"button\"></button>" ;} else{ echo date('H:i:s',strtotime($result->checkInTime));}?>" required parsley-maxlength="6" placeholder="checkInTime" disabled/>
```

Comment: `<button>` as the value of an input field? I don't think so. Does `if ($result->checkInTime == '0'||'NULL')` work?

Comment: Hm..yeah, you're right. Best way to do it would probably be to write the check outside the and then render the HTML.